# Read the contents of a Text Datablock

Tags: python, scripting

Writing into a text datablock can be done with the script

```
text = bpy.data.texts[name]
text.write(something)
```

However, when I used the script `text.read`, an error appeared.

Question: How do I read the content in a text datablock with a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`TextBlock.as_string()`**

Will give the complete contents of the text block.

Test Text block "FooBarBar"

```
Foo
Bar
Bar
```

Once again off to the python console to test.

```
>>> D.texts['FooBarBar'].as_string()
'Foo\nBar\nBar'

>>> print(D.texts['FooBarBar'].as_string())
Foo
Bar
Bar

>>>
```

same result as joining lines with

```
>>> '\n'.join(l.body for l in D.texts['FooBarBar'].lines)
'Foo\nBar\nBar'
```

On the error...

```
>>> D.texts['FooBarBar'].read
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'read'
```

The error appears in RED that the text block has no read method.  This is confirmed by consulting the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Text.html#bpy.types.Text.as_string)

My 2c worth of advice, try autocomplete in the console "[@MartinZ style](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/181189/15543)", consult the docs, and then....

Answer (score 2):

I have never needed to work with text blocks so I have no idea yet. Let's find out.

If you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after writing something in the Python Console, you can see all the available options from auto complete like this:

[image]

We can see that it is possible to access lines `text.lines` so if we want to read the 4th line for example we carry on with auto complete:

[image]

and see that it has `body`, that's probably the thing we need here then:

[image]

It's a string. That's it.